# Close woocommerce store on selected days and hours

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using the following PHP snippet to close woocommerce store in selected days (Monday and Sunday closed all day), but I need to add more days with different closing hours, for instance Friday open only from 00:00 to 14:00.
How should I modify the snippet?

```
// Custom conditional function
function is_shop_open() {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

    $start_time   = mktime('00', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); // 00:00h
    $end_time     = mktime('24', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); // 24:00h
    $now_time     = time();
    $allowed_days = in_array( date('N'), array(1, 7) ); // MONDAY AND SUNDAY ALL DAY
    
    return $allowed_days && $now_time >= $start_time && $now_time <= $end_time ? true : false;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'shop_closed_disable_purchases' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'shop_closed_disable_purchases' );
function shop_closed_disable_purchases( $purchasable ) {
    return is_shop_open() ? $purchasable : false;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'shop_open_allow_checkout' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'shop_open_allow_checkout' );
function shop_open_allow_checkout() {
    if ( ! is_shop_open() ) {
        wc_add_notice( __("En este momento la tienda está cerrada. Puedes ver los productos pero no puedes hacer pedidos. Informate en La Olla del Patio para saber los días habilitados para realizar pedidos."), 'error' );
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'shop_is_closed_notice' );
function shop_is_closed_notice(){
    if ( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) && ! is_shop_open() ) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<span class="shop-closed">%s</span>',
            esc_html__('En este momento la tienda está cerrada. Puedes ver los productos pero no puedes hacer pedidos. Informate en La Olla del Patio para saber los días habilitados para realizar pedidos.', 'woocommerce' )
        ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

I'm not a developer.

Comment: Why on earth would you close an online shop at certain times?

Comment: Well because is a shop for a local community where people sell the own vegetables and orders can be placed only during few days a week.